# How to set my job search status to not open?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I've got the following mail from the Stack Overflow:

> Your job search status is open, but not actively looking, but we need
>   more information before accelerating your matches. Once you tell us
>   just a little bit more about yourself, we’ll get you in front of
>   companies and send you any new jobs that match your interests.

I don't want to

- publicize my "developer story"
- search for jobs on the Stack Overflow

At least, not now. I don't close it out that once I will want to use that, but not now.

Yes, I could unsubscribe (there is an "unsubscribe" link below the mail), but this "job search status is open" thing annoys me a little bit.

How could I make this closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change this setting in your [job match preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current); changing it to 'Not interested in jobs' will have the effect you desire.

Comment: Why do some configuration pages use "me" and some use "current" to refer to the logged user?

Comment: Couldn't tell ya, we've been consistently using `current` lately, not sure when we decided not to use `me` anymore